# Traversing two-dimensional array, using for-in syntax

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsarray, fast-enumeration

I'm traversing through a two-dimensional array like this:

```
for (menuViewController *aSelection in mainDataArray) {
    ...
}
```

However, how do I access the lower arrays' data?
This following code doesn't work, but gives you the idea of what I mean:

```
for (menuViewController *aSelection in mainDataArray) {
    NSLog(@"Data: %@", [aSelection objectAtIndex:2]);
}
```

Comment: In what way doesn't it work? If `aSelection` is indeed an array, then that should do the trick. If it isn't (and it's not clear why you're typing it as something called `menuViewController` if it is), then why do you say you have a 2-D array?

Comment: Are you sure menuViewController is an array and not a viewController???

Comment: Yeah I can confirm that mainDataArray defo is an array. And it lists the array in NSlog. menuViewController is referring to my view controller, but maybe I have made an error here. What SHOULD that refer to??? It confused me to be honest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are traversing an array within an array, can you try the following?

```
for (NSArray* aSelection in mainDataArray) {
    NSLog(@"Data: %@", [aSelection objectAtIndex:2]);
}
```

Comment: Thank you user76859403, it was the NSArray syntax that I had got wrong (putting my viewController name there instead). Although it did work for one-dimensional array traversing!

Comment: I'd advise you to put the **type** that you are traversing. My guess is that **menuViewController** is not of type NSArray. But i can't see your code on how you used it the first time :)

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you do a second for-in statement

```
for (NSArray* aSelection in mainDataArray) {
    for (NSArray* bSelection in aSelection) {
        //Do something innovative :)
    }
}
```

Comment: Not a bad idea, thanks Eli Gregory, but the answer above fixes my problem.